# Movie where a couple survives only to reach hell?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Last year I went to a movie festival that lasted until dawn, I was a little drunk so I fell asleep during one of the films and woke up to a different one near the end where this couple were fleeing from people possessed by I believe demons and somehow reach a cavern beneath a hospital I think which was suppossed to be the entrance to Hell or a hellish dimension of some sorts. The movie ended as the couple just stared at the scenary realizing their attempts to escape were futile.

Something I did noticed was that the movie was probably before 2000, the fashion style didn't look recent. I think it was a movie from the late 80s or early 90s.

Does it ring a bell to anyone? Sorry if I don't provide much details, but that is as much as I could get from what I watched back then.

Comment: You could always Google the film festival's title and year, and see if they have a lineup of the films they showed.

Comment: If I did not do that was cuz it was something thrown together by a group of people at a local community center, no web page of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though perhaps older than you're thinking, it sounds like [Lucio Fulci's The Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082307/)

You can see the ending [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46R03LQEAx4)  The "surviving" couple think they've gotten away, but were actually being led deeper into hell.

Comment: yes, that's the movie, I had forgotten about the blank eyes but that triggered my memory

Answer (score 2):

This is quiet a shot in the dark but the description of the ending sound a bit like [Cabin in the woods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1259521/)?

Here is a clip of the ending, and the place just before that could, optically, qualify as Hospital.

Comment: not this one, it's too recent to be the one, though the film didn't seem to be low budget, it didn't look like a high budget one.